# processing successive promises with a timer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that displays the letters of the alphabet in the console, I want to make a promise in which a function is executed that displays the letters in the console, if successful, I want to clear the console, after that if the console is cleared, an inscription is displayed. I tried to implement this, but I only get letters, the code does not go to the next steps

```
function abc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    let abc  =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    let i = 0;
        const timeC=  setInterval(() => {
            i = (i > 5) ? 0 : i;
            console.log(abc[i]);
            i++;
        }
        ,300)
})}

function clear() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(timeC)
  }, 5000);
  };

  function changeText () {
      setTimeout(()=> {
          console.clear();
        console.log('abcdef');
      }, 5000);
  }

   abc()
    .then clear()
    .then(changeText)
    .catch(error=> console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems there.

1. You're never settling the promise you've created, so `changeText` is never called. To do that, call `resolve` to fulfill the promise once you're done with the letters, for instance:
2. `clear` doesn't have access to the `timeC` variable; that's private to the promise executor function (the function you pass `new Promise`). If you want to stop that interval timer after 5000ms, you'll need to do that within that executor function.

For example (see comments):

```js
function abc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        let abc  =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
        let i = 0;
        const timeC = setInterval(() => {
            i = (i > 5) ? 0 : i;
            console.log(abc[i]);
            i++;
        },300);
        // Stop the interval after 5000ms and
        // fulfill the promise
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(timeC);
            resolve();
        }, 5000);
    });
}

function changeText () {
    console.clear();
    console.log('abcdef');
}

abc()
    .then(changeText)
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

---

Side note: There's a handy trick you can use when incrementing `i`: the remainder operator (`%`):

```
i = (i + 1) % abc.length;
```

When `i` is going to go past the end of `abc`, it'll wrap around to the beginning again:

```js
function abc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        let abc  =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
        let i = 0;
        const timeC = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(abc[i]);
            i = (i + 1) % abc.length;
        },300);
        // Stop the interval after 5000ms and
        // fulfill the promise
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(timeC);
            resolve();
        }, 5000);
    });
}

function changeText () {
    console.clear();
    console.log('abcdef');
}

abc()
    .then(changeText)
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```